# can't access laravel in hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I tried hosting the application laravel I in byehost, but there is a problem when I access "**Whoops, looks like something went wrong**.".

env file content:

```
APP_ENV=local APP_DEBUG=true APP_KEY=base64:nprtp1ROnlQoqIWKGp6MefyMwy8X0Oy/nczEbeBzaHo= APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 DB_PORT=3306 DB_DATABASE=DB_SAMPLE DB_USERNAME=root DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file SESSION_DRIVER=file QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1 REDIS_PASSWORD=null REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io MAIL_PORT=2525 MAIL_USERNAME=null MAIL_PASSWORD=null MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: Chec k folder permission also update the question with hosting environments

Comment: you should not have spaces in `.env ` file

Comment: @BalrajAllam Yes this just got me a picture, not the same as the original.

Comment: @Jabaa I have access 755

Comment: update your question with more details otherwise you won't get proper help

Comment: try with sudo chmod 777 -R for  storage ,bootstrap and cache folder

Comment: @Jabaa Please wait I want to try ;)

Comment: @Jabaa did not work:(, I could not find the problem, when debugging on my env file is true but the error does not appear. only message ' Whoops, looks like something went wrong. '

Comment: `Whoops ...` is just a generic front-end message, the real error, which will tell you exactly what is wrong, will be in your `storage/logs/laravel.log`, and/or your webserver (Apache, nginx) and/or PHP logs.  What is the real error?

Comment: Also, why did you not post your original `.env`?  We can't help you if we we are looking at made-up data.

Comment: @Don'tPanic sorry I'm using laravel version 5.2 and php on my server version 7.0.2, I've been editing with the original env at my question.

Comment: Again: the real error, which will tell you exactly what is wrong, will be in your `storage/logs/laravel.log`. What is the real error?  Also, the .env in your question is now all messed up, formatting broken and impossible to read.  If you make it hard for ppl to help you, you won't get much help.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I just uploaded laravel which is still fresh, local when they run on smoothly but when on the hosting server I got the same problem of "Whoops, looks like something went wrong", whether in the php hosting server need to be configured?

Comment: For a third time: the real error, which will tell you exactly what is wrong, will be in your storage/logs/laravel.log. What is the real error?  Is my question not clear?

Comment: @Don'tPanic
This is the message that I can log in laravel.log : 

production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0).............................

Comment: And there is your answer.  Many, many duplicates of that question here on SO, and @Raza also answered it already here.

Comment: @Don'tPanic  
I've tried that way but still can't

Comment: The error shows that you did not create a key ...

Comment: @Don'tPanic I have the same problem with her ,

https://laravelquestions.com/php/laravel-no-application-encryption-key-has-been-specified/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to generate an app key. Simply run `php artisan key:generate` to generate the key locally, and simply copy it over to your `.env` file on hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Make right permission to the storage folder

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```